# GSL library in R

Tags: c, r

I am writing a C code that I will use in R. To do matrix operations in C, I added "gsl_matrix" library. When I compile using R CMD SHLIB it compiles without problem. However when I open R and try to write dyn.load("file.so"), I receive an error message:

```
unable to load shared object file.so
undefined symbol: gsl_matrix_alloc
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this has to do with your shared library that is not properly linked to GSL libs, as [discussed on R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2006-December/043927.html), or the manual on [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars), where it is suggested to use a `Makevars` file (with something like `PKG_LIBS=-L/usr/lib -lgsl`). Otherwise, following the example in `help(SHLIB)`, you may want to try:

```
$ R CMD SHLIB file.c -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

---

There is a simple tutorial, [R Call GSL](http://www.math.ncu.edu.tw/~chenwc/R_note/index.php?item=R_gsl), which shows basic setup for calling GSL functions.

I am able to reproduce the toy example, that I renamed `nperms.{c,r}` as follows (on a Mac, whence the use of a `-dynamiclib` switch in place of `-shared`):

```
~/scratch $ gcc -c nperms.c 
~/scratch $ file nperms.o
nperms.o: Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64
~/scratch $ gcc -dynamiclib -lgsl -lgslcblas -o libnperms.dylib -dylib nperms.o
~/scratch $ ls *nperm*
libnperms.dylib  nperms.c  nperms.o
~/scratch $ file libnperms.dylib 
libnperms.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Everything works fine when `dyn.load`'ing `libnperms.dylib` in R. However, using shared library generated from `R CMD SHLIB` without further argument

```
~/scratch $ R CMD SHLIB nperms.c
gcc -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -o nperms.so nperms.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
~/scratch $ ls *nperm*
libnperms.dylib  nperms.c  nperms.o  nperms.r  nperms.so
~/scratch $ file nperms.so
nperms.so: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

raises the following error (sorry for the French locale)

```
> dyn.load("nperms.so")
Erreur dans dyn.load("nperms.so") : 
  impossible de charger l'objet partag'e '/Users/chl/scratch/nperms.so':
  dlopen(/Users/chl/scratch/nperms.so, 6): Symbol not found: _gsl_permutation_alloc
  Referenced from: /Users/chl/scratch/nperms.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/chl/scratch/nperms.so
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. however i am quite new in linux, so can you tell me howto make makevars file? what should i write in it? thank you

Comment: @neticin Basically, it is a simple text file where you add compiler flags and library location, e.g. as in [this example](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-devel@r-project.org/msg06973.html). (`R CMD SHLIB` only include `-L/usr/local/lib`.) Dirk Eddelbuettel suggested to use an environment variable to make it easier, see [this thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-specify-compiler-options-when-using-R-CMD-SHLIB-td3088046.html).

Comment: I managed to solve this problem. Now another problem occured: 

dyn.load("metropC.so")
Erreur dans dyn.load("metropC.so") : 
  impossible de charger l'objet partagé '/home/asahin/src/metropC.so':
  /usr/lib64/libgsl.so.0: undefined symbol: cblas_ctrmv

Do you have any idea?

Comment: GSL may uses symbols from `libgslcblas` (You can check that with `gsl-config --libs` at your unix shell). Did you perhaps forgot `-lgslcblas` when building your shared library?

Answer (score 0):

I have not a direct answer to your question but did you try http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppGSL/index.html or http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppArmadillo/index.html?